# Calling a function on ng-click while not submitting a form with ng-submit

Tags: angularjs

Consider my (simplified) form:

```
<form ng-submit="save()">
    ...
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

After pressing "Save", it calls `ng-submit` on my form, whereas after pressing "Cancel", it calls a separate function (that re-directs me to another page)

The problem is that after pressing "Cancel" it also calls a function on `ng-submit`. I want it to just call its own function on `ng-click`. How can I solve this?

An obvious solution:

```
<form>
    ...
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

But I want an ability to submit the form by pressing Enter, which is why `ng-submit` was used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `type="button"` for cancel button
so it is

`<button type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>`

or use `<a>` tag instead, like:

`<a ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); cancel()">Cancel</a>`